# Running java from powershell with environment variables to specify the classpath

Tags: powershell

for the life of me I can't figure out how to convert this batch file to powershell. The java line is where I have the problems - I don't know how to insert environment variables correctly into it.

```
@echo off
SET runDir=../../../
java -cp %runDir%*;%runDir%lib/* helper.colors.AnsiColorKt
pause
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Please note, the java application must run within the powershell window, not an old-school Windows command prompt

Comment: It's not clear if this variable is required for the Java application itself. If it's not then you can easily replace it with a string.

Comment: yes that is my question, how do I replace that? I tried various ways but couldn't get it to work ... however I'm new to powershell. I tried $var or ${var} - the problem is that there is text immediately after what I want to replace.. and I wasn't sure if I need to enclose any of the arguments with strings - and if so, what parts

Comment: the windows batch file runs fine - it might look "not efficient" because actually I have multiple files a run.bat with the java stuff and other files that call it setting the environment variable first..however to make things easier to understand, I combined it into a more-or-less-minimum-whatchamacallit (term from stackoverflow) here

Comment: probably you're looking for gradle?  Although, who knows, maybe writing gradle build files in powershell is the way to go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace it literally: `java -cp ../../../*;../../../lib/* helper.colors.AnsiColorKt` or if you want to use a powershell variable

```
$rundir="../../../"
java -cp "$rundir*;$($rundir)lib/*" helper.colors.AnsiColorKt
```

Comment: thanks, maybe the problem was that I was trying to use `$env:runDir` directly.. so now I did `$rundir=$env:runDir` and it works - or maybe just I wasn't using the correct syntax for `${$var)`

Answer (score 0):

```
set-item -path Env:CLASSPATH -value C:\mytest 
java.exe -classpath $Env:CLASSPATH myApp
```